# Modify Apache CommonConfiguration to not to trim values

Tags: java, apache, configuration

I'm using Apache common-configuration library to read properties files for various reasons. My code is given below. By default, it strips the spaces before and after the values, which I want to avoid. Is there a way to do that?

```
CompositeConfiguration config = new CompositeConfiguration();
PropertiesConfiguration propertiesConfiguration = new PropertiesConfiguration();
URL url = CommonConfig.class.getResource("samplePropertiesFile.properties");
Reader reader = new FileReader(new File(url.getFile()));
propertiesConfiguration.read(reader);
config.addConfiguration(propertiesConfiguration);
```

Content of samplePropertiesFile.properties:

```
key=<space>value<space>
```

//both the space before and after must be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values are Java escaped<sup>1</sup>, so use `\u0020` for leading and trailing spaces that shouldn't be removed.

Only the first leading and last trailing space needs this, e.g.

```
key  =  \u0020  value  \u0020
```

will be the string `<sp><sp><sp>value<sp><sp><sp>`.

(OR)

Write CustomPropertiesConfiguration like the example in "Custom properties readers and writers" section in 
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html

<sup>1) According to [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/configuration/tags/CONFIGURATION_2_0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfiguration.java?view=markup#l829).</sup>

Comment: Thats a possible work around. Thank you for that. Is there any way to keep properties file intact and achieve the solution via code change?

Comment: Yes, of course there is. You .... eehhhhh .... *change the code!!?!?!!?* Step 1: Get the source code. Step 2: Make the change. Step 3: Compile and build new jar file. Step 4: Replace jar file in your classpath.

Comment: hmmmmm... I'm expecting something like this - Custom properties readers and writers section on https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html , which is for  PropertiesConfiguration, not CompositeConfiguration

Comment: Oops I missed it, my bad